# Finding sum of nos

Tags: real-analysis

I am unable to trace out from where the elements in $A_k$ would start,

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

First, note that the largest number in the set $A_k$ is $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.

Also, the number of elements in the set $A_k$ is $k$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It does not work, A_3 gets started to from 6 instead of 4...

Comment: @Raheel nope, its start from 4 anywhere your read from left to right(or count upword)

Comment: Indeed, it's easy to solve. I want to add that you need to look a while to notice usefull pattern. My answer suggests a general method.

Comment: How it would be helpful in finding the sum of elements in A_k?

Comment: Its the first step of ad-hoc solution that Oussama posted(and then others)

Answer (score 1):

Let's name $a_k$ the first element of $A_k$ and $S_k$ its sum, then, you can observe that it follows the following recurrence relation:

$$
a_k=a_{k-1}+k-1
$$

This yields:

$a_k-a_1 = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$

SO

$$
a_k=1+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}
$$

Hence, the sum $S_k$ would be:

$S_k= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (a_k+i) = ka_k+\frac{k(k-1)}{2} = \frac{k^2(k-1)}{2}+k+\frac{k(k-1)}{2} = \frac{k^3+k}{2}$

For example for $k=3$, you get:

$A_3 = \frac{27+3}{2}=15=4+5+6$

Comment: @bedbad Sorry, I don't get what you mean, could you clarify it further please?

Comment: You are right now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple general method for all such sequence - sum problems.

Start with D = S(i+1)-S(i) always for these problems(and you don't need to spot anything)

The sequence for D is a following.

k=2: D2 =  S3-S2 = 2+2+6

k=3: D3 =  S4-S3 = 3+3+3+10

k=4: D4 =  S5-S4 = 4+4+4+4+(k+1)(k+2)/2

Thus:

k=i: Di = S(i+1)-Si = i^2 + (i+1)(i+2)/2 = 3/2*k^2 + 3/2*k + 1

Sum(D, i) = Di+D(i-1)+...+D1+ = S(i+1) -S(1)
But it is just  = Sum(i, 1)[3/2*k^2 + 3/2*k + 1]

S(i+1) = Sum(i, 1)[3/2*k^2 + 3/2*k + 1] + S(1) = i^3/2 + i^2/4 + i/2  + 3*i^2/4 + 3*i/2 + i + S(1)

By progression formulas for i^2, i, 1

= i^3/2 + i^2 + 3*i + 1

I won't argue that it's the fastest one, but that's nobrainer(means it's a general method, just use calculus)

Also it will be as fast if you start with D` = S(i)-S(i-1).

Comment: From where and are you writing the terms for D_2 as 2+2+6 and so on for D_3 and D_4?

Comment: S - is the requested sum; " D = S(i+1)-S(i)" look at the top

Comment: You just substruct them as you see fit - the easiest was obviously is the 1st from the 1st, 2nd from the 2nd etc and the last one is left unmatch. 
You can start straight from the formula, I'm just showing sequence

Comment: In recurrence-sum questions, sums differences are always meaningful sequence, you can lookup up some in-depth explanations and articles why.

Answer (score 0):

$A_k$ set will have $k$ elements. Thus, $A_{k-1}$ will have $k-1$ etc. We must compute:

$$1+\sum\limits_1^{k-1} n$$
(where $1$ enters because $A_k$ starts with the next number)
This grows linearly in $k$ so, we compute the average value of $n$ and multiply it by the amount of terms.
$$\sum\limits_1^{k-1} n = \frac{k-1+1}{2}  (k-1) = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$

Sanity check: $A_3$ starts with 4 and indeed $1+\frac{3(3-1)}{2} = 4$.

EDIT:
How to compute the sum over $A_k$? We compute:
$$\sum\limits_{1 + \frac{k(k-1)}{2}} ^{k + \frac{k(k-1)}{2}} n$$

Again, we will compute the average of upper and lower bound and multiply it by $k$.

$$\big(k+\frac{k(k-1)}{2} + 1 + \frac{k(k-1)}{2}\big) \frac{k}{2} = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} +\frac{k^2(k-1)}{2} = \frac{k}{2}\big(k^2+1\big)$$

So, sum over $A_3$ will be: $4+5+6 = 15 = 3\times 5 = \frac{3}{2}(3^2 +1)$.
Hope this helps.

Comment: What are you trying to compute here? The sum of the elements of $A_3$ is $15$, not $4$.

Comment: The first element. OP is unable to track the first element. Ofcourse one can use the same reasoning to compute the sum of elements in $A_k$ by simply changing the indexes of the sum.

Comment: Dear your answer makes the reader turmoil, please expand it and find the sum of A_k th set.

Comment: @Raheel I have expanded my answer to compute the sum in question as well.

Answer (score 0):

$A_n$ has $n$ elements. Thus, the first element of $A_n$ is given by
$$\vert A_1\vert + \vert A_2 \vert + ...+ \vert A_{n-1}\vert+1 = 1+2+...+(n-1)+1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{i\in A_n} i = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+k \right) = n\cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n k$$
$$ = n\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: $=\dfrac{n}{2}(n^2+1)$

Comment: @TonyK mistake ;)

Comment: @bedbad: ??${}$

Comment: I'm sorry wrong answer. Answer with mistake was already edited.